# Twilio Functions: Add Parameters In Function Call

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-functions

I am new to Twilio's API, and for that matter, Twilio as a whole.

I'm using python to make an automated system in which, when an event happens, a call is placed to a particular number. Below is what I'm running (in Python):

```
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = 'ACxx...'
auth_token = 'xx...'

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

call = client.calls.create(
    url='my/twilio/function'
    to="+11111111111",
    from="+12222222222",
)
print(call)
```

And the following is my function in my Twilio account:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    twiml.say("A call was placed on the following extension.");
    callback(null, twiml);
};
```

This will successfully make the call to my test number, and plays the message "A call was placed on the following extension". However, what I would like is to be able to pass parameters to say on which extension the call was made, e.g., "A call was placed on extension 100". How do I accomplish passing this custom parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any query parameters or POST body parameters sent to your Function's URL should be available in the `event` argument to your Function. From your Python code, consider adding a query parameter to your Function URL with the data your Function will need (the extension dialed, it sounds like?). So instead of `/my/function` it would be `/my/function?extension=100`, which should then be available in your Function code as `event.extension`.

Comment: That worked! I don't know how I could've forgotten something so basic as passing parameters in urls. I do have one last issue, however. How do I reference the variable in a string? I attempted to run `twiml.say("A call was placed on extension %s", event.extension);`, and the call still went through, but the message just said "We're sorry, an error occurred" or something to that effect. I'm not familiar with node.js, but this is what I saw online about using placeholders and variables.

Comment: Disregard that last comment I made, I have found what I was doing wrong with the string formatting. Thank you very much for your help! I greatly appreciate it! :)